# Can't pass PHP variables through JQUERY and insert them into MYSQL

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I'm trying to send a form through jquery and it works fine sort of . 
When hitting the submit button my varibles:

```
$userid - got this variable from mysql and it's on top of my page (index.php)
$new_rand - generated this random number in file page_support. (support.php)
```

They are not proceded to the another file (page_jquery_new_ticket.php). 
Let me show you the code:

File: support.php

```
<div id="support">
<!-- START BACKGROUND SUPPORT -->
<div class="background-support">
    <div class="middle-container">
        <div style="position: absolute; bottom:0px;">
            <div class="font48 font-regular" >Pomoč i podrška</div>
            <div class="font24 inactive background-male" style="float:left;"><a href="?p=help">Pomoč</a></div>
            <div class="font24 active" style="float:right;"><a href="?p=support">Podrška</a></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- END OF BACKGROUND SUPPORT -->
<!-- MIDDLE INFORMATION FOR HELP STARTS HERE -->

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#new-ticket').on('submit',function(e) {

$.ajax({
url:'pages/jquery-pages/page_jquery_new_ticket.php',
data:$(this).serialize(),
type:'POST',
success:function(data){
console.log(data);
$("#success-creating-ticket").hide().html(data).fadeIn('slow');
}

});
e.preventDefault(); //=== To Avoid Page Refresh and Fire the Event "Click"===
});
});

</script>

<div id="success-creating-ticket">

</div>

<div class="middle-container">
        Prije nego što kontaktirate našu podršku molimo vas da pročitate sekciju „Pomoć“ gdje smo odgovorili na najčešća pitanja. U slučaju da vaše pitanje nije među njima pošaljite nam upit preko obrasca ispod i potrudićemo se da vam što prije pomognemo. 

        <br><br>
        <div class="font-italic">Podrška odgovara na vaša pitanja od ponedjeljka do petka između 10.00 i 16:00 sati</div> 
        <br>

        <?php 
            ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            // GET THE TICKET NUMBER IF ALREADY EXISTS CREATE NEW ONE 
            //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

            $statement = $dbConn->prepare("SELECT ticketnumber FROM tickets");
            $statement->execute();
            $view_ticket_number = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH);

            $rndnumber = rand(1001, 2000);
            $randnr = $rndnumber.$user_id;

            if($view_ticket_number['ticketnumber'] == $randnr) 
                {
                    $rndnumber = rand(1001, 2000);
                    $new_rand = $rndnumber.$user_id;
                    echo "<h1>#".$new_rand."</h1>";
                } else {
                    $rndnumber = rand(1001, 2000);
                    $new_rand = $rndnumber.$user_id;
                    echo '<div class="font-regular username_female font24">';
                    echo $settings_ticket." #".$new_rand;
                    echo '</div>';
                }

        ?>

        <br>

        <form method="post" action="" name="new-ticket" id="new-ticket">

        <input type="text" name="subject" class="width-50 " placeholder="Napisite naslov">
        <br><br>
        <textarea name="message" class="width-100" style="min-height: 100px;" id="message" placeholder="Napisite vase pitanje ovdje"></textarea>
        <br><br>
        <input type="submit" name="send" value="<?php echo $settings_btn_send;?>" class="button_pink_square"><br><br>
    </form>





</div>  
<!-- END OF MIDDLE INFORMATIO STARTS HERE -->
```

Here is the file: pages/jquery-pages/page_jquery_new_ticket.php

```
<?php   

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// THIS FILE CREATES NEW TICKET
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

include_once "../../inc/settings.php";
include_once '../../db/dbc.php';
include '../../languages/lang_bosnian_mainpage.php';


if(isset($_POST['send']) == $settings_btn_send) 
        {
        $subject = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['subject']);     //subject of the message
        $text = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['message']);        //text in the message
        $tid = mysql_real_escape_string(date("Y-m-d"));             //time when the message was sent

        //check if subject is empty
            if(empty($subject)) { 
                echo '<div class="error">';             
                echo 'Morate da napišete naslov';
                echo '</div><br>';
            } elseif(empty($text )) {
                echo '<div class="error">';     
                echo 'Morate da opišete vaš problem';
                echo '</div><br>';
            } else {

                //INSERT THINGS INTO THE DATABASE
                $statement = $dbConn->prepare("INSERT INTO tickets (user_id, ticketnumber, subject, message, tickettime, status) VALUES (:user_id, :new_rand, :subject, :text, :tid, :settings_ticket_new)");
                $statement->execute(array(
                        'user_id' => $user_id,
                        'new_rand' => $new_rand,
                        'subject' => $subject,
                        'text' => $text,
                        'tid' => $tid,
                        'settings_ticket_new' => 'Novi'
                ));
                echo '<div class="success">';
                echo 'Vaša poruka je poslana našoj podrsci. Uskoro ćemo odgovoriti na vaše pitanje';
                echo '<div>';
                //header("location: welcome.php?p=help");
            }


}


?>
```

When submitting in file (pages/jquery-pages/page_jquery_new_ticket.php) 
The variables $userid from my index.php are not recognized
and also $new_rand is not eighter recognized. How can i transfer them when submitting the page so i can insert them into the database.

I hope you understand my question.

Cheerz

Answer (score 0):

Your ajax call will serialize all the elements of the form `$('#new-ticket')` with names and pass them to your processing page.   userid isn't defined in that form, therefore it will never be passed across to that page in the ajax transaction.

If nothing else, define the user_id variable as a hidden element in the form, it'll then be serialized and sent across.